# Install GTK+ 3.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, 13.04, upgrade, gtk

How can I upgrade my GTK version?

I Have this version now:

```
axept@axept-NET:~$ dpkg -s libgtk2.0-0|grep '^Version'
Version: 2.24.20-1ubuntu1
```

I need version 3.0 to use the new released version of Banshee 2.9.0. How do I upgrade or install GTK 3.0?

On Ubuntu 13.04, and will it be the same way on 13.10?

Comment: Seems like Askubuntu isn't very newbie friendly since my question gets downvoted. Yes, maybe it's a stupid question, but since a installation says its missing, I need to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK 3.x is included by default in Ubuntu. You have both 3.x and 2.x installed.

If you are trying to install a version of Banshee which uses GTK 3.x, from source, you will need to install all the required development packages, to be able to compile it.

Comment: Ohh.. Yes, tried to install from source. Stopped becasue I needed 3.0. I thought I did install all packages needed to compile it? Well, maybe I missed something..

Comment: Used this guide: http://banshee.fm/download/development/

Comment: The `apt-get build-dep` mentioned there will install the build dependencies for the version already included in Ubuntu, not what is necessarily needed for a build from source, if any of those dependencies have changed. You will have to install `libgtk-3-dev` and other newer dependencies as required, manually.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Think I will pass this, got a new problem now, gio-sharp..